# cant connect from rails to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

im struggling to connect to my mysql service running on my local windows 7 machine- I am getting the following error when trying to rake migrations or access through the web browser-

```
Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)):
```

i have left the mysql user/pass as default - this is my yaml conf file

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  port: 3306
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: events_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: events_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: events_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

the thing is i can login using root through mysql on the command line and also running phpmyadmin through xampp- so i have narrowed it down to a firewall issue? or permissions issues? everything is running localhost on my machine

**update**

i turned windows firewall off and it made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i restarted the machine and restarted the servers- seemed to work

Comment: restarting machine and server did not work for me... In the end I found that ruby/rails was unable to resolve localhost to ip(127.0.0.1). I replaced localhost with the ip in config/database.yml file and the error went away!

Comment: The problem is because if you have IPv6 networking enabled on windows 7 then localhost resolves to "::1". You can verify this by running `ping localhost` from command prompt, the result should be `Reply from ::1: time<1ms`. Whereas mysql is usually configured for 127.0.0.1 bind address.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've granted localhost privileges. [Info here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,9293,9609#msg-9609).

Answer (score -1):

I'am a bit confused? Localost => Port (10061) ? 
Maybe try to add port: 3306 everywhere.

Do you started the Server in dev env?

Comment: if your confused do not answer the question 100061 is a winsock error